# What does OK = N do in a Windows Batch File?

Tags: batch-file

What does OK = N do in a Windows Batch File?
For example when you see files with the following at the beginning:

```
setlocal
OK=N
```

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: What you posted won't run in a batch file; it's a syntax error. Please post a **real** example of what you're asking.

Comment: If only I had someone like you for a compiler :),

Comment: The question really was concerning whether OK was a user-defined variable or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look valid to me at all.

Assuming you mean:

```
setlocal
set OK="N"
```

Then this is more about setlocal and endlocal than the set command.  From [This technet article on Batch files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750054.aspx):

> SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL
>
> The SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL commands are used together. When you use the
>   SETLOCAL command within a batch file, any environment changes you make
>   after that point are local to the batch file. For example, if you used
>   the SETLOCAL command followed by the:
>
> SET TEMP=C:\TEMP command, the batch file would recognize the TEMP
>   variable as containing the string C:\TEMP. However, if you were to run
>   a different batch file or open a different MS-DOS Window, the TEMP
>   variable wouldn't contain this string. To prevent future environment
>   variable changes from being local, you can use the ENDLOCAL command.

This means that you can use Environment variables to store things you might need to check or alter later on in your Batch file.  You could for example create a variable called OK, set it to "N", then do something else.  Based on the return value of something you can set it to "Y".  At the end of the Batch file you can check this again to see if you were successful or not.

This is just guesswork without seeing some working code you're talking about, but I think that's what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... So basically the file Im using doesn't ever reuse the OK variable, so in this context and based on your response the OK variable is something really that was used just for debugging that was left in and can be removed from the script... Also, your ability to ignore the syntax errors (missing "") and the ability to respond with a precise answer is greatly appreciated... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for set local:

http://www.computerhope.com/setlocal.htm